# Taking Domain into Consideration

Tags: functions

Let $f(x) = 0$, $g(x) = \ln x$

Find the domain of $f(x)g(x)$.

If I were to multiply both, together, I would get $0$, which is defined on the entire number line.

If I did it like a calculator, I wouldn't get a number for $g$ when $x$ was negative, and therefore $f(x)g(x)$ would be undefined for negative numbers.

I feel like the latter is correct, but what is the domain?

Comment: The function is defined as a product of two functions and so both domains must be observed. So yes, the latter is correct (in fact, $x$ cannot be zero either)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that multiplication is defined for all real numbers, so $fg(x)$ is well-defined whenever $f$ and $g$ are.

$f$ is well defined always, while $g$ is well-defined on $(0,\infty)$, so the product of these is well-defined on $(0,\infty)$, and is equivalent to the restriction of the zero function to $(0,\infty)$.

So the point to be careful about here is, that even if the function's value eventually (in our case, after multiplication by $f$) does not depend upon the input, that does not necessarily determine the nature or the domain of the input itself.